# Error en template Vuetify 'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, vuetify

Hola estoy usando una plantilla de vuetify y me sale el siguiente error ('v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier.), me podrian ayudar soy nuevo en esto
[image: 'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier.]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

La última versión de eslint ha añadido esa regla, que por lo que he visto en su [github](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1165) está siendo bastante discutida. Muchos slots de vuetify utilizan esa sintaxis que ahora está dando problemas.

Puedes deshabilitar esa comprobación en tu fichero .eslint

```javascript
    rules: {
     'vue/valid-v-slot': ['error', {
       allowModifiers: true
     }]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

En lugar de

```
v-slot:item.actions
```

utiliza:

```
v-slot:[\`item.actions\`]
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).